# split multiple records based on model year end month

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one record that I wish to split based on month.
When I am doing the split I am trying to copy all the data as is, but only interested to change the FromMonth field incrementally.

For ex,

```
    Record to be split:
    c1  c2  c3  c4  FromMonth  ToMonth  Y
    ---------------------------------------
    AA  BB  CC  DD  Feb         Dec    2013


    Resultant Records:
    1.)

    c1  c2  c3  c4  FromMonth  ToMonth  Y
    ---------------------------------------
    AA  BB  CC  DD  Mar         Dec    2013

    2.)
    c1  c2  c3  c4  FromMonth  ToMonth  Y
    ---------------------------------------
    AA  BB  CC  DD  Apr        Dec    2013

    3.)
    c1  c2  c3  c4  FromMonth  ToMonth  Y
    ---------------------------------------
    AA  BB  CC  DD  May         Dec    2013
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Any suggestions or ways to go about it will be useful.

here's what ive done, im new and I am just about learning:

```
    DECLARE @FromMonth Int;
    DECLARE @ToMonth Int;
    DECLARE @Result int;
    DECLARE @C1 int;
    DECLARE @C2 int;
    DECLARE @C3 int;
    DECLARE @C4 decimal(20,8);
    DECLARE @C5 uniqueidentifier;
    DECLARE @C6 varchar(1000);
    DECLARE @C7 int;
    DECLARE @C8 int;
    DECLARE @C9 int;
    DECLARE @C10 bit;
    DECLARE @C11 date;
    DECLARE @C12 date;
    set @FromMonth = (select FromMonth from master..t where t.c1=1 );
    set @ToMonth = (select ToMonth from master.t where t.c1=1 );
    set @Result=@ToMonth - @FromMonth;

    while(@Result!=0) 
    begin
    set @FromMonth = @FromMonth+1
    insert into master..t(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,FromMonth,ToMonth)
    values(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,@FromMonth,ToMonth);
    set @Result = @Result -1;
    break;
    end;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, but I really have absolutely no idea what you're talking about... what is "model year month"?  I cannot see any relation between the `TM` value of `12` being split into `03` and `04`

Comment: +1, totally no idea what you wanna do.

Comment: @freefaller,@dstronczak,sorry for not being specific, all i have to do is copy the row of data as is(multiple inserts) by incrementing the FM value all the way up to the TM value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to generate rows from 'FM' to 'TM' month, try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (c1  VARCHAR(10),c2  VARCHAR(10),c3  VARCHAR(10),c4  VARCHAR(10),FM  VARCHAR(10),TM  VARCHAR(10),Y VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @t VALUES
('AA',  'BB',  'CC',  'DD',  '02',  '12',  '13')

SELECT  a.c1
        , a.c2
        , a.c3
        , a.c4
        , number FM
        , a.TM
        , a.Y
FROM    @t a
JOIN    master..spt_values b ON
        type = 'P' 
AND     number > CAST(a.FM AS INT) AND number <= CAST(a.TM AS INT)
```

This example generates new rows from data found in a single row. It copies all fields except for the `FM` field, this fields takes the value of `spt_values.number`. Table `master..spt_values` is used to generate new rows.

For instance:

```
SELECT  number
FROM    master..spt_values b
WHERE   type = 'P'
```

will generate ordinal numbers from 0 to 2047. Join on that table is written so that it generates `TM` - `FM` number of rows ranging from 3 to 12.

**UPDATE**

Result of a `SELECT` statement can be inserted into a table, condition is that number and type of fields in table and result are the same. `INSERT` statement can take values to insert from an executed `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT  @t
SELECT  a.c1
        , a.c2
        , a.c3
        , a.c4
        , number FM
        , a.TM
        , a.Y
FROM    @t a
JOIN    master..spt_values b ON
        type = 'P' 
AND     number > CAST(a.FM AS INT) AND number <= CAST(a.TM AS INT)
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply, but I dont seem to understand the Join, All I want is to copy that row as is, but only focus on incrementing the FromMonth values all the way up to To Month.

Comment: You're welcome, I added explanation for using `master..spt_values` table. Generating new rows from a single row cannot be done without `JOIN` on some other table that has more than one row. If you're just learning SQL take a look at some of the tutorials about joining since this is one of the most important operations for data retrieval.

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan, It worked. how can I add the values back to the main table?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped. See the updated answer to see how you can insert result of a query into the table.